# Delphi memory leak in string?

Tags: string, delphi, memory-leaks, copy

I have a program which accepts an SQL query as a command-line argument, queries a PostgreSQL database and produces a file formatted in one of several ways (most often it's used to produce CSV files).

However, this program has som serious memory leaks - with one particular query that produces as 12MB file, the program uses 8GB of RAM plus several GB of swap space before the operating system kills it. I want to find the cause of this memory leak. I don't know Delphi very well (and judging by the quality of the program, neither did the original author), but I am tasked with finding a quick fix.

The following `doData` function portion of outputs a single row of the result set. I'd hazard a guess that the problem is with the "copy" command (creating a string on the heap that is never freed), but I'm sure someone more experienced than myself will be able to confirm this answer or point me in the right direction.

```
procedure doData;
var
    s, fldVal : string;
    i, fldLen : integer;
begin
    s := '';

    for i := 0 to ds.Fields.Count-1 do
    begin
        if (ds.Fields[i].DataType = ftDate) or
           (ds.Fields[i].DataType = ftDateTime) then
        begin
            if  psql.outDate = 'i' then
                fldLen := 8
            else
                fldLen := 10;

            if  ds.Fields[i].IsNull then
                fldVal := ''
            else
                fldVal := formatDate(ds.Fields[i].AsDateTime);
        end
        else
        begin
            fldLen := ds.Fields[i].DisplayWidth;
            fldVal := ds.Fields[i].AsString;
        end;

        if (psql.outType = 'd') or (psql.outType = 's') then
            s := s + trim(fldVal)

        else if psql.outType = 'f' then
        begin
            s := s + fldVal;

            if  fldLen - length(fldVal) > 0 then
                s := s + copy(spaces, 1, fldLen - length(fldVal));
                // Is this a memory leak above?
        end;

        if psql.outType = 's' then
        begin
            if i < ds.Fields.Count-1  then
           s := s + psql.outDelimChar;
        end
        else
            s := s + psql.outDelimChar;
    end;

    writeln(psql.outPrefixData + s);
end;
```

Comment: Delphi string type is managed with reference counts. When a string variable goes out of scope it is automatically destroyed. The `Copy` cannot create a memory leak in this code.

Comment: If you're producing a 12MB string then you're doing something wrong: Use TStringBuilder instead (or write directly to a stream). But using code like `s := s + xx` is very bad for memory handling

Comment: I have found `MadExcept` to be an effective tool for identifying memory leaks, but starting from your code fragment I would probably check where `ds` and `psql` get freed - you may get lucky ...

Comment: I've diagnosed *drastic* memory leaks like this before simply by placing breakpoints in certain spots, and watching the memory usage increase in Task Manager. (Note it may take a second to show up, that the Delphi memory manager doesn't immediately release back to the OS, etc, which can complicate it.) But in a situation in which it only goes up, and each increment is large, it's usually easy to find a section of code that causes it. You then narrow it down to a function, part of a function, and line.

Comment: Also my guess would be not strings (as LU RD explained) but object references held too long - ie, not freed as early as they could be. My guess would be copies of the data in the database query, ie the program is just holding everything in memory instead of doing whatever it has to per field and letting that data go before iterating to the next one. That is only a guess though. I can't see anything obvious in the above code. Narrow it down as per my above comment.

Comment: from what I can tell, I believe your issue is in data retrieval, i.e.  you execute a query that returns MANY records(rows), in fact so much, that it requires several GB of storage, what you need to do, is LIMIT the resulting records, in effect, page the result so that you never cache in memory more than a few hundred rows, you need to find the sweet-spot.

Answer (score 4):

There are no leaks in this code. The Delphi `string` type is managed by the compiler and requires no explicit memory deallocations from the programmer.

If you wish to find your leak you should include the full debug version of [FastMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/). This will produce diagnostics reports of any leaks in your code, including stack traces that help identify where the leaked memory was originally allocated.